# c# output text in multiple colors to a console inside a Parallel.For loop

Tags: c#, console-application

I've got a Parallel.For loop running which has to print text to the console in different colors. I used the code below to do this. However, when I run it here is what happens:

One thread writes "Item: " to the console but before it can write result[1], another thread writes "Item: ". I'd like to know if there's a way around this so I can get each thread to write everything to the console before the next thread starts writing.

```
Parallel.For(0, 256, i =>
    {
         //Irrelevant code omitted
         Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
         Console.Write("Item: ");
         Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
         Console.Write(result[1]);
         Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
         Console.WriteLine("[" + result[2] + "]");
    });
```

Comment: so... you basically want your code to run _sequentially_ - then why use `Parallel`?

Comment: I'm using Parallel to speed it up. I don't really want it to run sequentially. I just want result[1] and result[2] for each iteration to be outputted together (but in different colors)

Comment: You need `lock` around this code so output and colors don't get intermingled.